# Importing file into workspace generate Unable to resolve target 'android-5'

Tags: android, eclipse

I always encountered problem like this Unable to resolve target 'android-X',every time
I will import file in the workspace,last time also encountered like Unable to resolve 
target 'android-10', so i insatalled SDK Platform Android 2.3.3,..
now 'android-5',do i need to install again the SDK Platform Android 2.0?i tried to
fixed this by doing right click on the project and scroll down to Android Tools-->Fixed
Project Properties,but it is not working.Can you help me please.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unable to resolve target 'android-5' means that you do not have Android SDK level 5 APIs downloaded on your computer. Start the SDK manager, click the Obsolete check mark and then download the Level 5 APIs.

Alternatively, go into the project properties and change the target SDK version from android-5 to something else that is present on your computer.

Comment: correct . also , google suggests that you use the latest sdk number, so you should use 15 for now.

Answer (score 4):

Go into: Project>properties>Resource>Android>Project Build Traget> and select the available  target version! It will work-

Answer (score 2):

Go into: Project>properties>Resource>Android>Project Build Traget> and select the available target version! It will work

**If it gives error
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0**

Rightclick on project-->Android tools-->fix project properties

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was Right click on the project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.